# Does the `delete` keyword in PHP do what it does in C++ or similar?

Tags: php, reference, keyword

Just for curiosity, I typed `delete` on an editor with PHP syntax highlighting and it put it with a known keyword color.
There's `unset()` which when used on a reference I assume triggers garbage collection, resource freeing or whatever PHP does under the hood, but what does `delete` do?
When trying `delete $ref` on a reference variable, I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /... on line ...`

Answer (score 9):

Your editor is confused. There is no `delete` keyword in PHP.

If you look in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php), amusingly all it says is that it's a "dummy manual entry" for people who are really looking for `unlink()` or `unset`. For your case of getting rid of a reference variable, `unset` does the same thing except it doesn't destroy the value, only that particular reference.

Additionally, although it says `void delete ( void )` in the function prototype, no such function actually exists.

Comment: On a side note, you know human sanity is set to plummet when even a programming language's documentation editors are trolling other programmers...

Comment: Oh you're right, no object destroying, just reference unsetting.

Comment: @Petruza: They do get GCed once you remove all of their references, or when the script is shutting down.

Comment: Yes I know, such a high level language like PHP leaking memory wouldn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to meaning of 'delete' in C, you talk about 'unset()' function in PHP...

```
unset($var);
// or
unset($var1, $var2,...);
```